# ListView Group Header Can't resolve binding property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to group my items in Listview. I want to group them by "EventId" property and show EventId as header text. Groupping is working perfect, my items are groupped but the problem is, header text is empty for all groups.

Here is my xaml:

```
<ListView
    ItemsSource="{Binding CardEvents}"
    MinHeight="120"
    MaxHeight="120"                
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
    Name="CardEventsListView">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Kart Türü" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding CardType}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=cardEvent_headerA}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Oluşturma Tarihi" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding EventDateTime, Converter={StaticResource dateTimeConverter}}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=cardEvent_headerB}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Event Id" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding EventId}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=cardEvent_headerC}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Dakika" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Minute}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=cardEvent_headerD}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="İşlem Dk" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding RelativeMinute, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=timeSpanConverter}}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=cardEvent_headerE}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Op." DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding UserName}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=cardEvent_headerF}"/>
        </GridView>
   </ListView.View>
   <ListView.GroupStyle>
       <GroupStyle>
           <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding EventId}" />
               </DataTemplate>
           </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
       </GroupStyle>
   </ListView.GroupStyle>
```

In my Textblock, where i do the binding i get warning

> Cannot resolve symbol 'EventId'

I don't know why i can't access to EventId property while i can access it in GridViewColumn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot bind `EventId` of the ItemSource to your Group's DataTemplate, instead try using `Name` like

```
<DataTemplate>
     <TextBlock FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Name}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Here `Name` is the name of the group, as assigned by WPF but not from DataModel.

Reference - http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-grouping/